# The user name or password is incorrect. At System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.KerbS4ULogon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

In our ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application we want to get the security groups from the Active Directory of an logged in user. We use a custom login screen. In a code before (not listed here) the user will be authenticated by samaccountname and password. When the user is successfully authenticated, then his security groups will be queried from the Active Directory by the following code:

```
internal static IdentityReferenceCollection GetGroupsOfAdUser(string pSamAccountName, string pDomainName)
{
    // create an UPN (e.g. samaccountname@domain)
    var lUpn = string.Concat(pSamAccountName, "@", pDomainName);
    IdentityReferenceCollection lResult = null;

    using (WindowsIdentity lWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(lUpn))
    {               
        lResult = lWindowsIdentity.Groups;
    }

    return lResult;
}
```

We get an exception in this code. Here is an extract of the callstack:

```
The user name or password is incorrect. 
At System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.KerbS4ULogon [...] 
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(String sUserPrincipalName) […]
```

We cannot reproduce the problem, because the user was successfully authenticated one step before.

Authentication settings of the website in the IIS:

- Anonymous Authentication: Activated
- ASP.NET Impersonation: Deactivated
- Form Authentication: Activated

Note 1: The code works successfully @ our company location. The exception occurs in a different location with an different domain, active directory, etc..

Note 2: The code an login works with the Domain Admin.

Who knows where the problem is here and how can we fix this?

Comment: This smells like a nonexisting/bad SPN setting. I guess you verified that you have the correct IIS settings... What about your SPN settings? Are they identical / corresponding to your reference environment?